# General proof of $m^2 = E^2 - p^2$

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, mass-energy

All proofs I know of, starting from Einstein's famous 1905 article, only deal with special cases (actually, yes, I know that formula like $E=mc^2$ were known before Einstein in the context of electromagnetism). Would there be a more general proof? One that would work on curved spacetime for added bonus.

I am thinking of something along the following lines. Starting from the energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$, we could integrate $T^{00}$ and $T^{i0}$ over some region to get an energy and a momentum but do they always form a 4-vector in the simple Minkovskian case?

Comment: I have to say that this question confuses me... what's to prove?  There are versions of special relativity where this relationship is axiomatic.

Comment: Yes, true. Actually the usual proofs are more motivations than anything else, and eventually that $(E,p)$ forms a 4-vector is posited. But is it the only possible axiomatic? That's another, perhaps more accurate, way to ask the same question.

Comment: "*All proofs I know of, starting from Einstein's [...] 1905*" - This is incorrect. The Energy-Momentum Relation was first proven by Paul Dirac in 1928: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: @safesphere This is not correct. Schrödinger already knew of this relation in 1925, and Arthur C. Lunn in 1921, according to this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger_equation#Historical_background_and_development

Comment: @my2cts My comment is that the OP's statement regarding "1905" is wrong.

Comment: Also, just by the way that tensors work, the combination $j^{a} = u^{b}T_{b}{}^{a}$ is always a 4-vector.  But I don't see a route starting from there that will be any more satisfying than just positing the energy-momentum relationship.  Like, for this single-particle business to make sense, you have to presume an energy-momentum tensor like $T_{ab} = m_{0}\delta^{3}\left({\vec r}\right)u_{a}u_{b}$, where $u$ is some unit timelike normal, and what I call $\vec r$ is a spacelike 3-vector normal to $u$.  You can boost this, and see how it changes in different reference frames.

Comment: but at the end of the day, you're going to have to make some definitions about what energy, mass, and momentum are, and you'll just be assuming your conclusion when you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking of something along the following lines. Starting from the energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$, we could integrate $T^{00}$ and $T^{i0}$ over some region to get an energy and a momentum but do they always form a 4-vector in the simple Minkovskian case?

This is correct, when properly interpreted.

Working in flat spacetime (Minkowski metric), suppose that we have a tensor field $T^{AB}(x)$. In general, the quantities
$$
    P^A = \int dx^1\,dx^2\,dx^3\ T^{0A}(x)
\tag{1}
$$
will be functions of the remaining coordinate $x^0$. But if the tensor $T^{AB}(x)$ satisfies 
$$
\partial_A T^{AB}(x)=0,
\tag{2}
$$
then the quantities (1) are independent of $x^0$, and in this case we can show that the quantities $P^A$ are the components of a four-vector. To do this, consider two frames, $x$ and $\tilde x$, that are related to each other by a Lorentz transformation
$$
   \tilde x^A=\Lambda^A_B x^B
\hskip2cm
\text{with }\det\Lambda=1.
\tag{3}
$$
Let $v$ and $\tilde v$, respectively, be the timelike vectors with components $(1,0,0,0)$ in each of the two frames. These are related by
$$
   \tilde v^A=\Lambda^A_B v^B.
\tag{4}
$$
Now consider the quantities
\begin{align}
    P^F 
   & = \int \epsilon_{ABCD}\, dx^A\wedge dx^B\wedge dx^C\ v^D \,v_E T^{EF}(x)
\\
    \tilde P^F 
   & = \int \epsilon_{ABCD}\, d\tilde x^A\wedge d\tilde x^B\wedge d\tilde x^C\ 
  \tilde v^D \,\tilde v_E \tilde T^{EF}(\tilde x)
\tag{5}
\end{align}
where $\epsilon_{ABCD}$ is completely antisymmetric in its indices, normalized so that
$$
\det\Lambda = \epsilon_{ABCD}\Lambda^A_1\Lambda^B_2\Lambda^C_3\Lambda^D_4.
\tag{6}
$$
The integrals are written this way, instead of writing them as in (1), so that we can use the identity
$$
    \epsilon_{ABCD}\, dx^A\wedge dx^B\wedge dx^C\ v^D
   =  \epsilon_{ABCD}\, d\tilde x^A\wedge d\tilde x^B\wedge d\tilde x^C\ 
 \tilde v^D,
\tag{7}
$$
which is an obvious consqeuence of equations (3)-(4) and (6). Use (7) in (5) to get
\begin{align}
    \tilde P^F
    = \int \epsilon_{ABCD}\, dx^A\wedge dx^B\wedge dx^C\ v^D
  \,\tilde v_E \tilde T^{EF}(\tilde x).
\tag{8}
\end{align}
The assertion that $v$ and $T$ are *tensors* implies
$$
\tilde v_E \tilde T^{EF}(\tilde x)
=
v_E T^{EG}(x)\Lambda_G^F,
\tag{9}
$$
and using this in (8) gives
$$
\tilde P^F=\Lambda^F_G P^G,
$$
which is the desired result. In summary, *if the condition (2) is satisfied*, then the quantity (1) is a four-vector in the sense that if the construction on the right-hand side of (1) is repeated in two different frames, then the resulting quantities $P^A$ and $\tilde P^A$ are related (as four-vectors) by the same Lorentz transformation that relates those two frames.

By the way, the quantity $P_A P^A$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations, and it is interpreted as the invariant mass of the system.

For confirmation, here are a few on-line sources where the four-vector character of (1) is mentioned:

- Equations (4.35) and (4.67) in http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs12/qft1/Chapter04.pdf
- Equation (8.138) in  http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-7-conslaw.pdf
- Equation (1.43) in http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf

Comment: I am not sure I understand where you used (2) in the rest of the answer.

Comment: @frapadingue The only purpose of condition (2) is to ensure that the quantity (1) is independent of $x^0$. [To prove that it does ensure this, take the derivative of (1) wrt $x^0$, then use (2) to rewrite the integrand as a spatial gradient, whose integral is zero by the fundamental theorem of calculus.] This is important because (1) is a 4-vector only if it is independent of $x^0$. Otherwise, the effect of a Lorentz transformation would be nonsensical, because it would mix a free variable $x^0$ with the integration variables $x^1,x^2,x^3$.